# Not able to hit controller from a bot application visual studio

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller, botframework

I am having trouble hitting this controller from the browser. Its for a bot application and to get its token generated from the key. And the token expires soon so i made this controller that would generate it whenever needed. But i just cant hit it. When i do it returns me the default page html without hitting the controller itself. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question lacks important info. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to do?